# Store array of objects in PHP session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

How can I store/remove/get an array of objects in the PHP session?

I tried this for adding:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], serialize($item));
```

and this for removing:

```
function removeitem ($item)
{
    $arrayCart = $_SESSION['cart'] ;
    for ($i=0; $i<$arrayCart.length; $++ )
    {
        if ($item.id == $arrayCart[i].id)
            $arrayCart.splice (i,0); 
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work!!

Comment: Since when did php use dot notation??????? you are confusing js and php. i recommend buying a book, and using an ide

Comment: the glaring thing I see is use of serialize - this function is for writing to file or db - if your data is native php then keep it as php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['cart']=array();

$_SESSION['cart']['username'] = 'Admin';
$_SESSION['cart']['Password'] = '123';
.
.
.
?>
```

For Remove

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['cart']=array();

   unset ( $_SESSION['cart']['username'] );
    .
    .

or use Custom Function to Remove...
    .
    ?>
```

It's Work For Me...
if this code Report Errors Please Comment to Check this...

Please check PHP version

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
  $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
}
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
```

You don't need to serialize the item-variable - a Session can store pure Objects, as long as the max. session-size doesn't exceed.

If you want to remove Items from the cart, you should use index-Names - this allows you to find your items faster.

I would probably use something like this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
  $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
}

function addItem($itemName){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemName])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$itemName] = 1;
    }else
        $_SESSION['cart'][$itemName] ++;
    }
}
function removeItem($itemName){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemName])) {
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$itemName] > 0) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$itemName] --;
        }
    }
}

function clearCart(){
   unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

In this case, the cart stores each item and its amount. Instead of `$itemName`, you could also use the item-ID from your database.

To get an item from the cart, you will need this function:

```
function getItemCount($itemName){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$itemName])) {
        return $_SESSION['cart'][$itemName];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not pushing to array, because its probably not set yet, but to store to session, create new session var by:

```
$_SESSION['cart']=serialize($item);
```

to remove it:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
```

EDIT:

Thanks to comments I realized that above code wouldn't store array in session. So, another short solution is to store to session var some JSON. Try this for a short test:

```
$tmp = array(1,2,3);
$_SESSION['cart']=json_encode($tmp);
print_r(json_decode($_SESSION['cart']));
```

If that array is associative, you shoud use for decode:

```
json_decode($_SESSION['cart'], true);
```

Comment: but in this way I have only one object in my session..?

Comment: This would only allow one item in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

How has no one seen this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$arrayCart.length; $++ ){ //  <-----  lol @ $++
```

Make it `$i++`

You also need another 2 `}` to close your `if()` and `for()` statements so it's like this:

```
function removeitem ($item){
    $arrayCart = $_SESSION['cart'] ;
    for ($i=0; $i<$arrayCart.length; $++ ){
        if ($item.id == $arrayCart[i].id){
            $arrayCart.splice (i,0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I guess the code will work after your changes, however it isn't very efficient

Comment: Agreed but @Tom down below hit it on the head with a more useful answer

Comment: Furthermore, if a customer adds one product several times, it is also stored several times in the cart. If the item-id is used as the Array-Index, this can't happen. (and searching for an item also gets more efficient)